# on button click - open modal popup with dynamic details

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Have 3 buttons for each size of a product

```
<table width="100%" style="font-family:Calibri, Arial; margin-top:10px">
                <?php
                    while($prod_row = mysql_fetch_array($prod_result))
                    {
                        if($prod_row['name']<>"" && $prod_row['price']<>0)
                        {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:30px"><?php if($cat == "Design"){echo "Rs. ".$prod_row['price'];}else{echo $prod_row['name']." (Rs. ".$prod_row['price'].")";} ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle" id="buy_data"><a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="<?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']){echo '#buy_product';}else{echo '#login_buy';} ?>" id="<?php echo $prod_row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $prod_row['price']; ?>" title="<?php echo $prod_row['name']; ?>">Buy</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                        }//if closes
                    }//while closes 
                ?>
            </table>
```

On clicking the link, a modal popup should open showing some details of the clicked size

what i am doing is:

1. triggering an onclick event to store product details (of the clicked size) in session variables via session_product.php
2. displaying the modal with required details using these session variables

script for onclick event

```
$("#buy_data a").unbind("click").click(function(e){ 
    var productnumber = $(this).attr('id');
    var prodprice = $(this).attr('name');
    var prodsize = $(this).attr('title');
    var checkprodid = productnumber;
    $.post('session_product.php',{productid: checkprodid, productprice: prodprice, productsize: prodsize});
});
```

session_product.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['productprice'] = $_POST['productprice'];
$_SESSION['productsize'] = $_POST['productsize']
?>
```

modal popup

```
<div id="buy_product" class="modal hide fade well" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="buy_product_label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4 id="buy_product_label"></h4>
        <p style='color:#000'>
            Thank you <b><?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></b> for showing your interest in our website. You intend to purchase Product ID - <b><?php echo $_SESSION['prod_code']; ?></b><?php if($_SESSION['cat'] == "Photograph"){ ?> of size <b><?php echo $_SESSION['productsize'];} ?></b> worth Rs. <b><?php echo $_SESSION['productprice']."-".$_SESSION['cat']; ?></b><br /><br />
        <form id="thanks_popup" action="buy_email_notification.php" method="post">
            <input style="text-align:center" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="" name="buy_popup_submit" value="OK, Got it!" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem: on clicking a link, modal popup is showing product details corresponding to previously clicked link.

Please let me know where am i going wrong and what should be the solution to it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh request for popup.
Current browser document have the old data that generated from previous request.
Why don't you get the popup through ajax call?

Comment: is it possible to call popup in my script of onclick event?

Comment: Yes. But you should make your own ajax javascript function, and popup generator php script.